# Legend won't appear because I'm using fill instead of color

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend, fill

I have the following plot:

```
kleinebox<-ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point(aes(fill=Species), colour="black", pch=21, size=4)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#D89000","#35A2FF","#FA62DB"), 
  breaks = c("#D89000","#35A2FF","#FA62DB"), 
  labels = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.2, size=20), legend.position = "right")
```

Unfortunately, there is no legend appearing. This is due to the fact that I use `aes(fill=..)` in `geom_point()`. Because if I use `geom_point(aes(colour=Species), pch=21, size=4)` there is a legend. But I need to change the (fill) colours of my points because of the fact that I use pch=21, which is a coloured point but the edge is black. I need this for contrast.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a different dataset, ideally an included one like `iris`?

Comment: I'm not going to spend much time on this without a fully reproducible example, but the fact that you're trying to set/map `fill` differently in two different layers (boxplot/point) is a bit of a red flag for me.

Comment: Sorry, I've posted one with the iris dataset now.

Comment: Remove the `breaks` argument (or change it so that its the values of the variable, not the colors).

Comment: Wow that was an easy fix. Thank you so much. Post your comment as an answer, because I can't upvote comments yet..